# How do I make syntax highlighting on math mode in texmaker?

Tags: texmaker, syntax-highlighting

I have searched the web since yesterday and I couldn't find a way to setup syntax highlighting on math mode in texmaker.

When I write some equations on it, it gets the green color no matter if I am writing some math comands or a number, for example.

Texmaker is a great one, I think it could be better if it had sintax highlighting.

So, is it possible to do this configuration on texmaker? If yes, could you please say how to do this?

Comment: Looking briefly in the options, my guess is that the answer is "no". Contact the developer and make a feature request.